# sorting array in alphabetical order php / wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

How can I sort an array in alphabetical order using PHP on Wordpress CMS?

```
<?php if( count($terms_array) > 0 ) : foreach($terms_array as $term) : ?>

<?php 
    $term = '';
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'book',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $books_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $books_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: If you want to sort the results alphabetically, why are you retrieving them ordered by "menu_order"? Why not specify alphabetical order on the relevant field in your WP_Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you can uses the PHP function  to sort the array, here is the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). However, it's possible to sort the wp post by title. Here is the link https://codex.wordpress.org/Alphabetizing_Posts

Regards.
Ed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the default sort function in php. Assuming its the $terms_array that you want to sort,

```
<?php 
sort($terms_array);

if( count($terms_array) > 0 ) : 

foreach($terms_array as $term) :

        $term = '';
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'book',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        $books_query = new WP_Query( $args )

        if ( $books_query->have_posts() ) : 
?>
```